# Decode Json urls

Tags: java, json, parsing, url, encoding

I'm manually parsing Json objects using java and I have a problem with urls.

They currently look like this:

```
http:\/\/a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/...
```

and I was wondering how to decode them into a normal form that I can further use, like this:

```
http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net//hphotos-ak-ash4//...
```

It's not just the slashes that cause this problem, so simply searching for them is not a solution.
I'm searching for a standard method from the jdk that could easily accomplish this.

Unfortunately I have know idea what the encoding is called, so I can't be more specific in what I want to know.

Comment: Why parse JSON manually? Unless it's for learning, it sounds a bit like reinventing the wheel http://www.json.org/java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should try and use the answer from here:

[unEscape JavaScript escaped value in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882036/unescape-javascript-escaped-value-in-java)

There seems to be an unescape function. I have used that before in javascript (unescape) to help with the same issue. Looks like Java has a similar function.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html