# How to load images from html in the AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In the AsyncTask, I am getting a json with some of the values as images. Below is the sample of my json

```
{ 
  "text": "some text",
  "html1": "Hi, check out my fb profile picture at <img src = 'http:\/\/abc.com/image1.png'\/> ",
  "html2": "Hi, check out my whatsapp profile picture at <img src = 'http:\/\/abc.com\/image1.png'\/> ",
   .
   .
   .
}
```

In async task postExecute Method I have

```
( ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.html1 ) ).setText( Html.fromHtml( ( String ) jsonObj.get( "html1" ), new ImageGetter()
{
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable( String source )
    {
        return loadImage( source );
    }
}, null ) );
 ( ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.html2) ).setText( Html.fromHtml( ( String ) jsonObj.get( "html2" ), new ImageGetter()
    {
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable( String source )
        {
            return loadImage( source );
        }
    }, null ) );
```

and my loadImage method looks like below

```
private Drawable loadImage( String source )
    {
        Drawable drawable = null;
        URL sourceURL;
        try
        {
            sourceURL = new URL( source );
            URLConnection urlConnection = sourceURL.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( bufferedInputStream );

            // convert Bitmap to Drawable
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable( getResources(), bm );

            drawable.setBounds( 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight() );

        }
        catch ( MalformedURLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return drawable;
    }
```

I think the code is suffice but I am getting **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

I have added the internet permission in manifest.xml

Comment: can you please debug to the specific line when the code crash?

Comment: @ urlConnection.connect();

Comment: I am not sure, but probably you shouldn't work with network in onPostExecute method. And the only method in AsyncTask where you can do it is doInBackground method. This can cause android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: Ok, how to get multiple drawables in doInBackground method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ImageGetter {
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView mTv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String source = <your source from json here>;

        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(source, this, null);
        mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mTv.setText(spanned);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
        Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

        new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

        return d;
    }

    class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

        private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String source = (String) params[0];
            mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + source);
            try {
                InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
                mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                mDrawable.setLevel(1);
                // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
                // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
                CharSequence t = mTv.getText();
                mTv.setText(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or:
Add StrictMode code in OnCreate under setContentView(...);

```js
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

But adding StrictMode.ThreadPolicy is a bad practise

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that the json format for the url cause all the trouble

there is a great post on that issue: [Decode Json urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211553/decode-json-urls)

but it end up with dead links.. so.. a little bit of googling around and: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

you should unescape your url string with the unescapeJavaScript function to get a proper url

Comment: any chance to share the exception inner message?