# How to unescape cookie value in java which was escaped in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies

Am setting a `cookie` like below, in one jsp page.

```
document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape("#{myBean.cookieValue}");
```

And am retrieving `cookie` value in my target jsp page using `request.getCookies();`.

Am getting the value of cookie in my target jsp page. But, the value being set in the cookie contains `space` like `31st July 2012`. So, when I print this cookie value in my target JSP page, am getting `31st%20July%202012`.

In my target JSP page I just want to show the exact initial value like `31st July 2012`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unEscape JavaScript escaped value in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882036/unescape-javascript-escaped-value-in-java)

Comment: yes, probably - all you need is to use the java equivalent of unescape() when you print the cookie value.

Comment: Finding it difficult to use unescape() in a scriplet.
`<% String cookieValue = "";
   String actualValue = "";
 ...  
cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
actualValue  = **unescape**(cookieValue);
%>
It says "The method unescape(String) is undefined for the type (Name of my jsp page)"