# Compilation error using "{" string in Playframework 2.5.x templates

Tags: playframework

Got a compilation error using string "{" in Playframework 2.5.8 template expression like

```
<div>@{"{" + value}</div>
```

however these both compile

```
<div>@{"x" + value}</div>
<div>@("{" + value)</div>
```

It seems I need some escaping there?

Comment: Yes you need to escape it. What is your question?

Comment: The question is about escaping format, I found only @@ case in docs

Comment: [This question might be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764679/guide-to-proper-escaping-in-play-framework/14837123)

Comment: Didn't help. And it is for 1.2

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts got round with

```
@defining("{"){e => @{e + value}}
```