# How to generate identical cookies from Java and from Javascript (without enclosing double-quotes)

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, urlencode

I try to make a cookie's value generated from the server side (in Java) identical to a cookie's value generated from this [jquery's cookies librarie](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/), which use :

```
encodeURIComponent( value )
```

to encode the cookie value.

Let's take this example string :

```
a b,c;d*~'"()!±
```

I use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611117/843699), in Java, to encode a cookie value :

```
String result = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8")
                          .replaceAll("\\+", "%20")
                          .replaceAll("\\%21", "!")
                          .replaceAll("\\%27", "'")
                          .replaceAll("\\%28", "(")
                          .replaceAll("\\%29", ")")
                          .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~");
```

I then add the cookie to the response :

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("testCookieServerSide", encodeValue("a b,c;d*~'\"()!±"));
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

This *adds double-quotes around the value!* :

```
"a%20b%2Cc%3Bd*~'%22()!%C2%B1"
```

When encoding the same value using the jquery library, I get the same value but without the double-quotes :

```
a%20b%2Cc%3Bd*~'%22()!%C2%B1
```

Is it possible to tell Java to *not* generate the double-quotes? I've heard of *cookie.setVersion(0)* or *cookie.setVersion(1)* but this doesn't seem to change anything.

When retrieving those two values on the server-side, they are identical after a :

```
URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
```

... the double-quotes are removed. Great.

But on the client side, *the two values are differents*!

```
alert($.cookies.get('testCookieServerSide')); => "a b,c;d*~'"()!±"
alert($.cookies.get('testCookieClientSide')); => a b,c;d*~'"()!±
```

Any idea on how to generate the exact same value? How do you deal with this?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but what happens if you try encoding/decoding the string value first (using functions like the ones suggested here: http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html ) I know it's old, but that's all I saw for emulating encoding/decoding of UTF8 in javascript.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the help. The problem is not how the characters are encoded, this is identical on both side. The problem is that Java adds extra double-quotes around the value (when there are special characters).

Comment: The answer you can find here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582334/java-cookies-and-double-quoted-marks][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582334/java-cookies-and-double-quoted-marks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix I found :

I didn't find any way to tell Java to stop adding those double-quotes, so I have to live with them.

I modified the [jquery's cookies library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/) I use, so instead of decoding the cookie value like this :

```
value = decodeURIComponent( pair[1] );
```

It uses:

```
value = decodeURIComponent( pair[1].replace( /^"(.*)"$/, '$1' ) );
```

When this line of code is reached, the value in the cookie is still encoded (the js library itself encode it on the client-side and I encode it using Java on the server-side, using the above code). So the double-quotes, at the begining and end of the value, if not encoded, *are necessarily characters added by Java*... They have to be removed when getting the value.