# How to create cookie without quotes around value?

Tags: http, servlets, cookies, quotes

I need to create cookie with e-mail address as value - but when I try to - then I have result:

"someone@example.com"

but I would like to have:

someone@example.com

The cookie should be created without double quoted marks - because other application uses it in such format. How to force java to not to add double quoted? Java adds them because there is special char "at".

I create the cookie that way:

```
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("login", "someone@example.com");
    cookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
    cookie.setDomain("domain.com");
    cookie.setVersion(1);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's indeed caused by the `@` sign. This is [not allowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setValue-java.lang.String-) in version 0 cookies. The container will implicitly force it to become a version 1 cookie (which breaks in MSIE browsers). You'd like to [URL-encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the cookie value on cookie's creation

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("login", URLEncoder.encode("someone@example.com", "UTF-8"));
cookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
cookie.setDomain("domain.com");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

and [URL-decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) it on cookie reading

```
String value = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
```

Note that you should for sure not explicitly set the cookie version to 1.

#### See also:

- [Why do cookie values with whitespace arrive at the client side with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572482/why-do-cookie-values-with-whitespace-arrive-at-the-client-side-with-quotes/7233959#7233959)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, cookies are visible and manipulatable by the enduser or man-in-the-middle. Carrying the email address around in a cookie is a bad smell. What if the enduser changes it to a different address? Whatever functional requirement (remembering the login?) you thought to solve with carrying the email address around in a cookie should most likely be solved differently.

#### See also:

- [How do I keep a user logged into my site for months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185951/java-how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-my-site-for-months/2186072#2186072)

Comment: That's what I need, and it works perfectly, thanks BalusC (for login suggestions also)

Comment: Missing an 'r' in URLDecode, should be URLDecoder :)