# Cookie set by Application server having double quotes

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, jetty

I am trying to set a cookie with value unkown#4?Wn5pZ1JwQnlLEGRJAgB4WQU%3D in Servlet response.

But when I set the cookie in browser it is returned with quotes surrounding it like this:

"unkown#4?Wn5pZ1JwQnlLEGRJAgB4WQU%3D".

Why is this happening? We are using Jetty as application server.

I will put code which I have written

```
String cookieValue = "unkown#4?Wn5pZ1JwQnlLEGRJAgB4WQU%3D";
Cookie zedoCookie = new Cookie("cookiename", cookieValue);
zedoCookie.setMaxAge(31536000); // this is one year duration.
zedoCookie.setDomain("somedomain.com");
zedoCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(zedoCookie);
```

Can someone put some light on this?

I have already had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582334/java-cookies-and-double-quoted-marks). But it does not seem to address my issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like Jetty 8 (or earlier) treats the following characters as not allowed in Cookies: `"\\n\r\t\f\b%+ ;=` ([HttpFields](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/e1c516c7d1937b8604864dfe57236877ef5be4ea/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpFields.java) -> `__COOKIE_DELIM`). If one of these characters is contained in the value of the cookie, then the value will be enclosed in double quotes in the HTTP-Header.
URL-Encoding does not solve the Problem, since then you will still have the `%` character inside. To me it seems like a bug. I posted a question to the [Jetty mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03095.html). There is also another post on the mailing list, which explains why the cookie version is raised in Jetty version 9.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this.  I had convert '+' -> '-', '/' -> '.', and '=' -> '_' to get my base64 cookie to be stored without spaces.