# How to pass caret symbol in URL?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, url

I need to pass `^` like a value of parameter in URL. For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/books?filter=^
```

But have an `error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986. I've read, that I need to encode. Have something like this, but it still doesn't work. I also try to add 
    System.setProperty("tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow" ^ ");

but for `^` it doen't help.

I have a controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/books")
public String getBooks(@RequestParam(value = "filter") String filter, Model model)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String par = URLEncoder.encode(nameFilter,"UTF-8");
    List<Books> books = (List<Books>) booksService.findAll(filter);
    model.addAttribute("books", books);
    return "getBooks";
}
```

}

Comment: Try  [http://localhost:8080/myapp/books?filter=%5E](http://localhost:8080/myapp/books?filter=%5E). See [HTML Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this, it will help:

https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html

[@Mark’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889174/how-to-pass-caret-symbol-in-url#comment92691137_52889174) is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the URI before doing a request to your REST Api

For instance, when you're using JS read this:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp
On Java: [Java URL encoding: URLEncoder vs. URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321873/java-url-encoding-urlencoder-vs-uri)

Goodluck!