# Unable to decode base64 string in java

Tags: java, string-decoding

I am trying to decode base64 string. But somehow it is not decoding complete string. Below is base64 string.

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 ... gMCwwXkdCIDc3OCwgMTE5NiwgMkJeRlMgDQpeTEgwDQpeWFoNCg==

I can decode this base64 string https://www.base64decode.org/ and it decodes it correctly. But when I tried to decode it using code then it break in between.(I am not sure bur because of some special character.) Below is the code which I am using to decode.

```
StringUtils.newStringIso8859_1(Base64.decodeBase64(labelResponse.getLabelUrl().getBytes()))
```

I don't know what is going wrong.

Output which I am expecting.

```
^XA
^LH16,12
^LL1212
^FT 581, 403 ^AUN  ^FD0005^FS ^FX Configurable Text 1
^FT 500, 587 ^AUN  ^FDC004^FS ^FX Configurable Text 2
^FT 510,  90 ^AVN, 70, 75 ^FDVOID^FS ^FX Test Label

^FT  20, 343 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FDJames^FS ^FX Shipper Name
^FT  20, 373 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FDPB^FS ^FX Shipper Address
^FT  20, 403 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FD37 Executive Dr^FS ^FX Shipper Address
^FT  20, 433 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FDBerwick ME 03901^FS ^FX Shipper City State Zip
^FT  20, 463 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FD^FS ^FX Shipper Country Code

^FT 148, 634 ^A0N, 32, 35 ^FDJohn Smith^FS ^FX Consignee Contact
^FT 148, 662 ^A0N, 32, 35 ^FD1 Union Ave^FS ^FX Consignee Name
^FT 148, 690 ^A0N, 32, 35 ^FDDanbury CT 06810-5953^FS ^FX Consignee Address 1
^FT 148, 718 ^A0N, 32, 35 ^FD^FS ^FX Consignee Address 2
^FT 148, 746 ^A0N, 32, 35 ^FD^FS ^FX Consignee City State Zip

^FT 212,  25 ^AQN ^FD$13.36^FS ^FX USPS Postage (& Fees) Paid
^FT 212,  51 ^AQN ^FDUS POSTAGE^FS ^FX USPS Postage (& Fees) Paid
^FT 212,  77 ^A0N, 28, 21 ^FD05/21/2016^FS ^FX Shipment Date
^FT 212, 105 ^A0N, 28, 21 ^FD06810^FS ^FX Origin zip
^FT 212, 133 ^A0N, 28, 21 ^FD3 lbs 12 ozs^FS ^FX Package Weight
^FT 212, 161 ^A0N, 28, 21 ^FDZone 1^FS ^FX Destination zone

^FT 364, 134 ^AQN, 22, 14 ^FB270,1,0,C ^FDPitney Bowes^FS ^FX PB
^FT 364, 160 ^AQN, 22, 11 ^FB270,1,0,C ^FDComBasPrice^FS ^FX PB
^FT 364, 189 ^A0N, 32, 22 ^FB270,1,0,C ^FDNO SURCHARGE^FS ^FX PB

^FT 501, 134 ^A0N, 22, 20 ^FB270,1,0,R ^FD022W0030000012^FS ^FX PB
^FT 501, 160 ^A0N, 22, 20 ^FB270,1,0,R ^FDpbSmartPostage^FS ^FX PB
^FT 501, 186 ^A0N, 22, 20 ^FB270,1,0,R ^FD0000004242^FS ^FX PB

^BY2,2.2,^FS
^FT 373, 103 ^B7N,5,5,,18,N ^FH^FD022W04    3x7500=T
 c^FS ^FX Indicia
^BY3,2.0,^FS
^FT  60,1040 ^BCN,154,N,N,N,N^FD>;>842006810>89406109898644001564484^FS ^FX Tracking Barcode
^FT 0,1094 ^AT ^FB776,1,0,C, ^FD9406 1098 9864 4001 5644 84^FS ^FX Tracking Barcode text

^FT   0, 256 ^AUN  ^FB776,1,0,C, ^FDPRIORITY MAIL 1-DAY?^FS ^FX USPS Mail Class
^FT  24, 175 ^AVN,264,264  ^FDP^FS  ^FX  Service ICON

^FT   0, 856 ^AT  ^FB776,1,0,c, ^FDUSPS SIGNATURE TRACKING #^FS ^FX e/ USPS DELIVERY CONFIRMATION
^FT  40, 539 ^A0N, 24, 32  ^FD^FS ^FX Restricted Delivery
^FT 557, 296 ^APN  ^FDDelivery Date: 05/23/2016^FS ^FX Scheduled Delivery Date
^FO 748, 313 ^ADR ^FD^FS ^FX Custom Message

^LRY^FT5,805 ^GB 770,,65^FS
^FT60,800^AUN ^FDTEST LABEL - DO NOT MAIL^FS

^FT   0, 818 ^GB 776,   0, 12B ^FS
^FT   0,1121 ^GB 776,   0, 12B ^FS
^FT   0, 274 ^GB 776,   0,  6B ^FS
^FT   0, 206 ^GB 776,   0,  6B ^FS
^FT 203, 203 ^GB   0, 203,  4B ^FS
^FT 496, 595 ^GB 111,  51,  1  ^FS 
^FO   0,   0 ^GB 776,1198,  2B ^FS 
^LH0
^XZ
|^|
^XA
^LH12,10
^LL1212

^FT  70,  20 ^AQR ^FDPS Form 3816 January 2014 Facsimile^FS
^FT  70, 880 ^AQR ^FB310,1,0,R ^FDCopy 1 - Delivery Unit^FS

^FT  10, 100 ^APR ^FDFollow Proper Scanning procedures for COD delivery and clearance^FS
^FT  50,  20 ^APR ^FD1. DO NOT allow the recipient (addressee or agent) to examine contents before payment^FS
^FT  30,  20 ^APR ^FD2. DO NOT deliver this article until payment is collected^FS
^FT  50, 810 ^APR ^FD3. If payment is by check, enter check number above^FS
^FT  30, 810 ^APR ^FD4. Have customer sign form 3849^FS

^FT 745,  10 ^ASR ^FDDELIVERY EMPLOYEE - Remove copies 1 & 2 at Time of delivery^FS

^FT 655,  15 ^AQR ^FB315,3,0^FDCollect the amount shown below, If customer pays by CHECK or MO payable to the mailer.^FS
^FT 655, 352 ^AQR ^FB280,3,0^FDCollect the amount shown below, if customer pays by CASH (includes MO fee(s))^FS

^FT 200,  20 ^AQR ^FDDelivered By^FS
^FT 200, 410 ^AQR ^FDDate Delivered^FS
^FT 133,  20 ^AQR ^FDDate Payment Sent to Mailer^FS
^FT 200, 640 ^AQR ^FDCheck Number^FS
^FT 133, 410 ^AQR ^FDMoney Order Number(s)^FS

^FT 385,  20 ^ARR ^FDFROM:^FS
^FT 360, 100 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FDJames^FS
^FT 330, 100 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FDPB^FS
^FT 300, 100 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FD37 Executive Dr^FS
^FT 270, 100 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FDBerwick ME 03901^FS
^FT 240, 100 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FD ^FS
^FT 385, 638 ^ARR ^FDTO:^FS
^FT 360, 680 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FDJohn Smith^FS
^FT 330, 680 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FD1 Union Ave^FS
^FT 300, 680 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FDDanbury CT 06810-5953^FS
^FT 270, 680 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FD^FS
^FT 240, 680 ^A0R, 28, 20 ^FD ^FS

^FT 485,  20 ^AQR ^FDDate of Mailing^FS
^FT 447,  20 ^ARR ^FB200,1,0,C ^FD05/21/2016^FS
^FT 535,  55 ^AQR ^FDRegistered Mail Service^FS
^FT 535,  25 ^AQR ^FB25,1,0,C ^FD^FS
^FT 535, 340 ^AQR ^FDPriority Mail Express Service^FS
^FT 535, 310 ^AQR ^FB25,1,0,C ^FD^FS
^FT 435, 255 ^AQR ^FB210,3,0 ^FDRemit COD charges to Sender via Priority Mail Express^FS
^FT 455, 220 ^AQR ^FB30,1,0,C ^FDX^FS
^FT 485, 475 ^AQR ^FDUSPSCA No.^FS

^FT 590,  20 ^AQR ^FB105,2,0    ^FDCheck/MO Amount^FS
^FT 595, 135 ^ASR ^FB220,1,0,C  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FT 590, 352 ^AQR ^FB 75,2,0    ^FDCash Amount^FS
^FT 595, 435 ^ASR ^FB195,1,0,C  ^FD$500.00^FS

^FT 435,960 ^ASR, 120,100  ^FDCOD^FS
^BY2,3.0^FS
^FO 595, 680 ^BCR,80,N,N,N,N^FH^FD>;>842006810>89406109898644001564484^FS
^FT 540, 755 ^A0R, 38, 30 ^FD9406 1098 9864 4001 5644 84^FS

^FO  90,  10 ^GB 330,1178, 2B ^FS
^FO 420,  10 ^GB 310, 620, 2B ^FS

^FO 640,  10 ^GB   0, 620, 2B ^FS
^FO 512,  10 ^GB   0, 620, 2B ^FS
^FO 572,  10 ^GB   0, 620, 2B ^FS
^FO 572, 342 ^GB 160,   0, 2B ^FS
^FO 420, 215 ^GB  92,   0, 2B ^FS
^FO 420, 465 ^GB  92,   0, 2B ^FS
^FO  90, 400 ^GB 135,   0, 2B ^FS
^FO 158,  10 ^GB   0,1178, 2B ^FS
^FO 225,  10 ^GB   0,1178, 2B ^FS
^FO 158, 628 ^GB 292,   0, 2B ^FS

^FO 453, 220 ^GB  25,  25, 2B ^FS
^FO 530,  25 ^GB  25,  25, 2B ^FS
^FO 530, 310 ^GB  25,  25, 2B ^FS

^FO   0,   0 ^GB 778,1198, 1B ^FS 
^LH0
^XZ
|^|^XA
^LH12,12
^LL1218

^FO 10, 20 ^AQR^FDPS Form 3816 January 2014 Facsimile ^FS
^FO 10, 970 ^AQR^FDCopy 2 - Payment ^FS
^FO 145, 15 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDPOST OFFICE: Return this copy to mailer with money order(s) or check. Mail payment for only one ^FS
^FO 110, 15 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDCOD per EM04 envelope(mailer address will appear in the window). Please secure this copy in the ^FS
^FO 75, 15 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDenvelop with tape, if necessary. ^FS
^FO 375, 45 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDFROM : ^FS
^FO 350, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDJames ^FS
^FO 320, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPB ^FS
^FO 290, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD37 Executive Dr ^FS
^FO 260, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDBerwick ME 03901 ^FS
^FO 230, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD ^FS
^FO 200, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD ^FS
^FO 375, 645 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDTO : ^FS
^FO 350, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDJohn Smith ^FS
^FO 320, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD1 Union Ave ^FS
^FO 290, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDDanbury CT 06810-5953 ^FS
^FO 260, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD ^FS
^FO 230, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD ^FS
^FO 200, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD ^FS
^FO 555, 25 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDDELIVERY EMPLOYEE: Turn in this copy ^FS
^FO 520, 25 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDwith the payment you received for the COD ^FS
^FO 485, 25 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDarticle and the signed PS Form 3849. BE ^FS
^FO 450, 25 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDSURE THE COD NUMBER APPEARS ON ^FS
^FO 415, 25 ^A0R, 30, 28  ^FDTHE MONEY ORDER(S) OR CHECK^FS
^FO 625, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCheck/MO^FS
^FO 600, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmount^FS
^FO 615, 150 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FO 625, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCash^FS
^FO 600, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmount^FS
^FO 615, 480 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FO 715, 25 ^A0R, 48, 40  ^FDMail payment for only one COD per envelope^FS
^FO 410, 960 ^ASR, 120,100  ^FDCOD^FS
^BY2,3.0^FS
^FO 590, 675 ^BCR,80,N,N,N,N^FH^FD>;>842006810>89406109898644001564484 ^FS
^FO 520, 725 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD9406 1098 9864 4001 5644 84^FS


^FO 185,15^GB 475, 600, 2B ^FS 
^FO 185,615^GB 222, 570, 2B ^FS
^FO 405,15^GB 0, 600, 2B ^FS
^FO 593,15^GB 0, 600, 2B ^FS
^FO 593,325^GB 65, 0, 2B ^FS


^FO 0,0^GB 778, 1196, 2B ^FS 
^LH0
^XZ
|^|^XA
^LH12,12
^LL1218

^FO 10, 20 ^AQR^FDPS Form 3816 January 2014 Facsimile^FS
^FO 10, 970 ^AQR^FDCopy 3 - Mailer^FS
^FO 150, 910 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPostmark^FS 
^FO 150, 630 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCOD Fee^FS 
^FO 115, 650 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD$6.65^FS
^FO 80, 630 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPostage^FS
^FO 40, 650 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD$13.36^FS
^FO 150, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCheck and Enter Amount (If Applicable)^FS
^FO 100, 75 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDUSPS Tracking^FS
^FO 60, 75 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDSignature Confirmation^FS
^FO 100, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDRestricted Delivery^FS
^FO 60, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDSpecial Handling^FS
^FO 110, 535 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDReturn^FS
^FO 85, 535 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDReceipt^FS
^FO 60, 490 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmt^FS
^FO 35, 530 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD$0.00^FS
^FO 375, 45 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDFROM:^FS
^FO 350, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDJames^FS
^FO 320, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPB^FS
^FO 290, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD37 Executive Dr^FS
^FO 260, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDBerwick ME 03901^FS
^FO 230, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 200, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 375, 645 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDTO:^FS
^FO 350, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDJohn Smith^FS
^FO 320, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD1 Union Ave^FS
^FO 290, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDDanbury CT 06810-5953^FS
^FO 260, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 230, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 200, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 465, 35 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDDate of Mailing^FS
^FO 435, 65 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD05/21/2016^FS
^FO 515, 75 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDRegistered Mail Service^FS
^FO 515, 355 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPriority Mail Express Service^FS
^FO 595, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCheck/MO^FS
^FO 570, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmount^FS
^FO 585, 150 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FO 595, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCash^FS
^FO 570, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmount^FS
^FO 585, 480 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FO 655, 25 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FDSee USPS.COM for claims information^FS
^FO 695, 25 ^A0R, 48, 40  ^FDSAVE THIS RECEIPT^FS
^FO 450, 950 ^ASR, 120,100  ^FDCOD^FS
^BY2,3.0^FS
^FO 640, 675 ^BCR,80,N,N,N,N^FH^FD>;>842006810>89406109898644001564484^FS
^FO 580, 725 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD9406 1098 9864 4001 5644 84^FS

^FO 516, 49 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Registered Mail Service
^FO 516, 329 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Priority Mail Service
^FO 96, 505 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Return Receipt
^FO 56, 304 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Special Handling
^FO 96, 304 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Restricted Delivery
^FO 56, 44 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Signature Confirmation
^FO 96, 44 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Usps Tracking

^FO 40,15^GB 590, 600, 2B^FS 
^FO 40,615^GB 387, 570, 2B^FS
^FO 185,15^GB 0, 1170, 2B^FS
^FO 425,15^GB 0, 600, 2B^FS
^FO 502,15^GB 0, 600, 2B^FS
^FO 563,15^GB 0, 600, 2B^FS
^FO 563,325^GB 65, 0, 2B^FS
^FO 40,900^GB 145, 0, 2B^FS
^FO 110,615^GB 0, 285, 2B^FS
^FO 100,40^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 60,40^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 100,300^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 60,300^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 100,500^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 520,45^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 520,325^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS

^FO 0,0^GB 778, 1196, 2B^FS 
^LH0
^XZ
|^|^XA
^LH12,12
^LL1218

^FO 10, 20 ^AQR^FDPS Form 3816 January 2014 Facsimile^FS
^FO 10, 970 ^AQR^FDCopy 4 - Mailing P.O.^FS
^FO 150, 910 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPostmark^FS 
^FO 150, 630 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCOD Fee^FS 
^FO 115, 650 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD$6.65^FS
^FO 80, 630 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPostage^FS
^FO 40, 650 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD$13.36^FS
^FO 150, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCheck and Enter Amount (If Applicable)^FS
^FO 100, 75 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDUSPS Tracking^FS
^FO 60, 75 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDSignature Confirmation^FS
^FO 100, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDRestricted Delivery^FS
^FO 60, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDSpecial Handling^FS
^FO 110, 535 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDReturn^FS
^FO 85, 535 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDReceipt^FS
^FO 60, 490 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmt^FS
^FO 35, 530 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD$0.00^FS
^FO 375, 45 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDFROM:^FS
^FO 350, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDJames^FS
^FO 320, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPB^FS
^FO 290, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD37 Executive Dr^FS
^FO 260, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDBerwick ME 03901^FS
^FO 230, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 200, 105 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 375, 645 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDTO:^FS
^FO 350, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDJohn Smith^FS
^FO 320, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD1 Union Ave^FS
^FO 290, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDDanbury CT 06810-5953^FS
^FO 260, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 230, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 200, 705 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD^FS
^FO 465, 35 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDDate of Mailing^FS
^FO 435, 65 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD05/21/2016^FS
^FO 515, 75 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDRegistered Mail Service^FS
^FO 515, 355 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDPriority Mail Express Service^FS
^FO 595, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCheck/MO^FS
^FO 570, 30 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmount^FS
^FO 585, 150 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FO 595, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDCash^FS
^FO 570, 335 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FDAmount^FS
^FO 585, 480 ^A0R, 28, 20  ^FD$500.00^FS
^FO 655, 25 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD^FS
^FO 695, 25 ^A0R, 48, 40  ^FDRetain at Mailing Post Office^FS
^FO 450, 950 ^ASR, 120,100  ^FDCOD^FS
^BY2,3.0^FS
^FO 640, 675 ^BCR,80,N,N,N,N^FH^FD>;>842006810>89406109898644001564484^FS
^FO 580, 725 ^A0R, 38, 30  ^FD9406 1098 9864 4001 5644 84^FS

^FO 516, 49 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Registered Mail Service
^FO 516, 329 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Priority Mail Service
^FO 96, 505 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Return Receipt
^FO 56, 304 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Special Handling
^FO 96, 304 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Restricted Delivery
^FO 56, 44 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Signature Confirmation
^FO 96, 44 ^A0R, 30, 30  ^FD^FS ^FX Usps Tracking

^FO 40,15^GB 590, 600, 2B^FS 
^FO 40,615^GB 387, 570, 2B^FS
^FO 185,15^GB 0, 1170, 2B^FS
^FO 425,15^GB 0, 600, 2B^FS
^FO 502,15^GB 0, 600, 2B^FS
^FO 563,15^GB 0, 600, 2B^FS
^FO 563,325^GB 65, 0, 2B^FS
^FO 40,900^GB 145, 0, 2B^FS
^FO 110,615^GB 0, 285, 2B^FS
^FO 100,40^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 60,40^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 100,300^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 60,300^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 100,500^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 520,45^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS
^FO 520,325^GB 25, 25, 2B^FS

^FO 0,0^GB 778, 1196, 2B^FS 
^LH0
^XZ
```

Thanks,
Awadhendra

Comment: What is your exact error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error message. But it is not converting all results.

Comment: java.util.Base64 is able to decode it and gets the same result as the website you linked - what framework does your Base64 belong to?

Comment: I am using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 this library.

Comment: commons codec Base64 also seems perfectly happy with the text you pasted in your question originally so I suspect that you need to confirm that new labelResponse.getLabelUrl().getBytes() is giving you what you think it is.

Comment: Can you paste the decoded string which you get. As I am still not getting full output.

Answer (score 1):

It should be problem with default charset on your system. Try this,

```
StringUtils.newStringIso8859_1(Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
```

Your JVMs default charset should be other than UTF-8. In the above code UTF-8 `Charset` is passes

Comment: Can you post the decoded string. So that I can confirm.

Comment: What stopping you from trying it?

Comment: I tried this code. Even all the combination of charset. But still I am not getting correct result.

Comment: Can you add the output you are expecting to the question? I am getting the same output as from https://www.base64decode.org/.

Comment: I had added output string.

Comment: When I tried your code then it returns only 37 lines while base64decode url returning almost 350 lines.

Comment: I got exact output as yours. Check the string you got here, labelResponse.getLabelUrl()

Comment: Which library you are using. I had written this code. StringUtils.newStringIso8859_1(Base64.decodeBase64(decodeString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))). and package is import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;\

Comment: I think I am also getting same output. The problem is with copy value function of intelije IDE. It is not copying all values. I will verify few more time and if everything is fine I will mark this as answer :-)

Comment: As of v6, Java SE ships with JAXB. javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter has static methods that make this easy. So you might try this way to decode your string. This might work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify how do you obtain the image? If it is from a server that you control, or from an artifact that returns the image, you must be sure that there are not special character in the base64 image string. You can do that using for example, the Javascript function encodeURIComponent(). If you are working with Java you can check this link to see its equivalent [Java equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent that produces identical output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu)

Comment: In original string, it contains special character. It is not image base64. It is base64 for ZPL string which have indecia data. Indecia data contains special character.