# JS encodeURI Equivalent of Java

Tags: java, html, encoding

I have a file path:

```
file://///10.10.10.10/Yev Pri - Ru─▒n G├╢z├╝yle Ortado─Яu.pdf
```

This is shown as:

```
file://///10.10.10.10/Ye%20Pri%20-%20Ru%E2%94%80%E2%96%92n%20G%E2%94%9C%E2%95%A2z%E2%94%9C%E2%95%9Dyle%20Ortado%E2%94%80%D0%AFu.pdf
```

within `<a/>` tag of HTML when I inspect it. I want to generate same string at Java. When I encode it with

`URLEncoder.encode(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName())`

```
file%3A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F10.10.10.10%2FYev+Pri+-+Ru%E2%94%80%E2%96%92n+G%E2%94%9C%E2%95%A2z%E2%94%9C%E2%95%9Dyle+Ortado%E2%94%80%D0%AFu.pdf
```

It seems that browser applies `encodeURI()`. How can I get the same string with browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent that produces identical output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu)

Comment: @KarlReid thanks for the link. However that answers don't apply to my question. This is a URL path and `/` are not encoded by browser?

Comment: Fair enough, sorry. It looks like @VGR's answer here does what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLEncoder is for encoding form data.  To create an escaped URL or URI, use the [java.net.URI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

```
URI uri = new URI("file", "///10.10.10.10/Yev Pri - Ru─▒n G├╢z├╝yle Ortado─Яu.pdf", null);
String escapedURI = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Note:  You cannot use `new URI("file://///10.10.10.10/Yev Pri - Ru─▒n G├╢z├╝yle Ortado─Яu.pdf")` because that constructor does not perform percent-escaping of characters which may not legally appear directly in URIs.  The class documentation explicitly specifies that the one-argument constructor expects the argument to already have proper escaping.

Comment: So, I cannot use this as answer?

Comment: You can use the URI constructor that takes *three* arguments, as my code block uses.  You cannot use the URI constructor that takes one argument.