# Replace white space with %20

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have to replace all withe space in a string with %20.

I try to use the method `replaceAll` in this mode `title.replaceAll(" ", "%20");`(obviously title is a String) but this doesn't work and the results is the initial string with all white space

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. Try `String replaced = title.replaceAll(" ", "%20");`

Comment: You did capture the new String into another variable, right? (hard to tell since you didn't provide enough code to say ...)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu

Comment: or lil better `String replaced = title.replace(" ", "%20");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

Don't use replace all I find it doesn't ever work as expected. Just String.replace and that should get the job done just fine.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    String test = "H E L L O";

    test = test.replace(" ", "%20");
    System.out.println (test);

}
```

**Result**

```
H%20E%20L%20L%20O
```